# Can't get fan working on thermostat

Tags: furnace, thermostat

I recently purchased a new thermostat. My old thermostat worked for heat (no AC either) but the fan wouldn't go on when I turned to "On" (in hopes to move some cool air from the basement up during the summer).

Same thing appears to be happening on the new one but having trouble with my wires in general. I have 2 red wires, 2 black and 1 green. The thermostat is looking for a G,Y,W,RC,RH.

I put one black to the G and W connectors and the G to RH. Where would the 2 red go?

[image: Here is a photo of my panel on furnace]

Any insight would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where were the wires before? What are the labels on the terminals? Does the blower have a wiring diagram or instructions? Where do each of the wires go? It doesn't look like there's enough information to answer this question as written. Please update it and flag it to be reopened after doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Connect the green wire to the `G` terminal in the furnace, and the other end of that wire to the `G` terminal on the thermostat. Connect one of the black wires to the `W` terminal in the furnace, with the other end of the wire connected to the `W` terminal on the thermostat. Then connect one of the red wires to the `R` terminal in the furnace, and the other end to the `Rh` terminal on the thermostat. If it's a fancy WiFi thermostat, you could connect the other red wire to the `COM` terminal in the furnace, with the other end of the wire to the `C` terminal on the thermostat

If you ever add A/C, you'll connect a jumper between `Rh` and `Rc` at the thermostat. Then you'll run a wire from the `Y` terminal in the furnace, to the `Y` wire on the thermostat